# Gradient Descent Algorithm Doesn't Converge

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, logistic-regression

I'm trying to make a simple classifier using Python and here's my code(It's not all of it but I'm certain the problem is from this part.):

```
def grad(theta, X, y, m, lam):
    return (1 / m) * (X.T.dot(h(X, theta) - y)) + (lam / m) * theta

for i in range(400):
    # We shouldn't regularize the first theta so get a copy of it to change it back to normal
    first_t = theta[0]
    # Perform gradient descent
    theta = theta - a * grad(theta, X_train, Y_train, m_train, lam)
    # Change the value of the first theta to what it's supposed to be
    theta[0] = first_t - (a / m_train) * sum(X_train[:, 0] * (h(X_train, theta) - Y_train))
```

But even with a training case as simple as X = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]] Y = [0,1,0,1] which says whether a number is even or not(1 for yes and 0 for no) it still doesn't converge after 400 iterations.I thought I'd change the value of alpha, lambda or the number of iterations but none worked but in case you're wondering, `a = 0.001` and `lam = 0.0001`!
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: (Linear) Logistic regression can only fit linearly separable problems, yours is not.

Comment: @dedObed so is the gradient descent algorithm fine? Because I tried it on a real data set and it had a very poor performance

Comment: I'm not willing to judge without a working example. Toy around with artificial data that are [linearly separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability), if you can't find the problem yourself, it will help you to get help here :-)

Comment: @dedObed I have a question: Can't we seperate the data by a line with a slope of 0? Like y = 0*x + 0.5?What's the difference?

Comment: What data? The odd-even one? The line y = 0.5 just goes below all the data, so a respective classifier will assign everything to the same class. Try to draw it, really....

Comment: @dedObed I think I misunderstood something.  When we draw the line, wouldn't half the data(The y value) be under the line(the y-value would be 0) and the other half above the line(Pardon my English)?

Comment: You need to look at the X space, you do not know the target variable when new datapoint comes ;-)